# Merge arrays of objects by condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have array of objects - original items

```
originalItems = [
   {name:"aaa", expanded: false, visible: true},
   {name:"bbb", expanded: false, visible: true},
   {name:"ccc", expanded: false, visible: true}
]
```

then I do some changes on items

```
currentItems = [
   {name:"aaa", expanded: true, visible: false},
   {name:"bbb", expanded: false, visible: true},
   {name:"ccc", expanded: true, visible: true}
]
```

Now I need to merge those two arrays,

**BUT**: in the merged arrays (result), I need that *expanded* value will be from *currentItems*, and *visible* will be from *originalItems*
something like this

```
result = [
   {name:"aaa", expanded: true, visible: true},
   {name:"bbb", expanded: false, visible: true},
   {name:"ccc", expanded: true, visible: true}
]
```

Is there some elegant way to achieve it? Or just go through properties?

Comment: does `currentItems` has the same order as `originalItems`?

Comment: yes, it's the same order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on one of the arrays, for example the original one, and transform each object into a new object by spreading the properties of the original object ([...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) into a new object. You can then set the `expanded` property to take the value from its corresponding object in the `currentItems` via the index (`i`). See example below:

```js
const originalItems = [ {name:"aaa", expanded: false, visible: true}, {name:"bbb", expanded: false, visible: true}, {name:"ccc", expanded: false, visible: true} ];
const currentItems = [ {name:"aaa", expanded: true, visible: false}, {name:"bbb", expanded: false, visible: true}, {name:"ccc", expanded: true, visible: true} ];

const res = originalItems.map((obj, i) => ({
  ...obj,
  expanded: currentItems[i].expanded
}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're taking the elements from two different arrays of the same length to create a third, you can create a new array, then loop through the number of objects in the array, constructing your result object based on the desired source list.

```
let result = [];
for (i = 0; i < originalItems.length; i++) {
  let newObj = {
    name: originalItems[i].name,
    expanded: currentItems[i].expanded,
    visible: originalItems[i].visible,
  };
  result.push(newObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd sort and manage arrays like this, for simplicity as well speed. Perhaps more on par with what you were looking to do.

```js
let Items = [
    { name: "aaa", expanded: false, visible: true },
    { name: "bbb", expanded: false, visible: true },
    { name: "ccc", expanded: false, visible: true }
]



function doExpand(name, val) {
    let item = getItem(name);
    item.expanded = val;
}
function doVisible(name, val) {
    let item = getItem(name);
    item.visible = val;
}
function addItem(name) {
    if (!getItem(name)) {
        Items.push({ name: name, expanded: false, visible: false });
    } else {
        console.log("duplicates found");
    }
}

function getItem(name) {
    for (let i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {
        if (Items[i].name === name) return Items[i];
    }
    return false;
}

/* TESTING TIME */

doExpand("aaa", true);
doExpand("aaa", false);
let Item = getItem("bbb");
Item.name = "renamed";
addItem("dogsnacks");
addItem("bacon");
addItem("programming");
addItem("programming");
addItem("programming");
addItem("programming");
addItem("programming");

console.log(Items);
```

Comment: For is faster than Map; as a heads up if goals are to be efficient.